# For loop inside an always block with conditional statement giving unexpected error

Tags: verilog

I have tried looking at different posts related to for loop inside an always block but my problem looks different. Here's the part of my code of interest :

```
   always@(posedge clk) begin
     for(i=2;i<UP_SPACES+2;i=i+1) begin  //Ram_out
        if(up_addr_d2[3:0]==i) 
        begin
          up_dout_t2     <= ram_out[(i+1)*32-1:i*32];                                                                                                    
        end
     end// for loop
  end
```

I have declared i as an integer. Here the compiler gives the error 'i is not a constant'. I was not sure if one can code this way and was expecting a multidriver error but this error i dont understand. Please throw light.

Answer (score 2):

This line is illegal:

```
up_dout_t2     <= ram_out[(i+1)*32-1:i*32];
```

It is illegal to have a variable value of the right hand side of the colon in a part-select. Basically, this is illegal:

```
i[a+3 : a]
```

Instead, you have to say:

```
i[a+3 -: 4]
```

where `a+3` is the starting index, `-:` means *count down* and `4` is the width. So, instead of

```
i[a : a+3]
```

you have to say:

```
i[a +: 4]
```

The direction of the index of `i` doesn't matter. These lines of code would work for either

```
reg [big:little] i;
```

or

```
reg [little:big] i;
```

So, your line of code should be:

```
up_dout_t2     <= ram_out[(i+1)*32-1 -: 32];
```

or:

```
up_dout_t2     <= ram_out[i*32 +: 32];
```

Comment: Thanks. Would you know why it's illegal though?

Comment: @KrishnaDheerajPutrevu this is illegal based on the verilog spec. I can't say I know why that is the case though. See section 7.4.6 of the spec: https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2017.html