# Quartus Prime throwing an error at a $error command

Tags: verilog, fpga, system-verilog, quartus, intel-fpga

I am having a problem with the following code which should simply throw an error at compilation
if my number of inputs is not divisible by my number of outputs.

```
module multiplexer #(parameter N_INPUTS, parameter N_OUTPUTS) (in, out, select);

    generate
        if (N_INPUTS % N_OUTPUTS != 0) begin
            $error("%m ** Illegal Parameter ** NUMBER OF INPUTS(%d) does not divide into NUMBER OF OUTPUTS(%d)", N_INPUTS, N_OUTPUTS);
        end
    endgenerate

    input wire [N_INPUTS-1:0] in;
    input wire [$clog2(N_INPUTS/N_OUTPUTS) - 1:0] select;
    output wire [N_OUTPUTS-1:0] out;

    always @ (select, in) begin
        out = in[(select + 1) * N_OUTPUTS - 1:(select + 1) * N_OUTPUTS - N_OUTPUTS];
    end

endmodule
```

But Quartus keep throwing me this error when I proceed to an Analysis:

```
Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at multiplexer.v(5) near text: "$error";  expecting "end". Check for and fix any syntax errors that appear immediately before or at the specified keyword. The Intel FPGA Knowledge Database contains many articles with specific details on how to resolve this error. Visit the Knowledge Database at https://www.altera.com/support/support-resources/knowledge-base/search.html and search for this specific error message number.
```

I am beginning to wonder wether or not the compiler of Quartus supports the $error command (it's my first time using it).

I would greatly appreciate any help on the subject since I am still a beginner in the domain :)

Comment: I'll try that. Just let me a couple of minutes to know how to enable this thing :P

Comment: Does SystemVerilog have the same syntax and everything (just more feature basically)? Because when I look online it tells me to change the extension of my file from .v (for Verilog) to .sv (for SystemVerilog).

Comment: I'll try finding a way to simply activate it because if I change my file to SystemVerilog I think my other file may start bleeding errors as they all contain always block and I am noticing that SystemVerilog as some special always block for every type of logic. But thank you for all the help I am pretty sure that this question is now solved. I would have liked to mark your answer as the right one but you only commented...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close your Quartus project and in the `.qsf` file, change the line pointing to your `multiplexer` module verilog file from:

```
set_global_assignment -name VERILOG_FILE multiplexer.v
```

To:

```
set_global_assignment -name SYSTEMVERILOG_FILE multiplexer.v
```

**Edit:**

Also set:

```
set_global_assignment -name VERILOG_INPUT_VERSION SYSTEMVERILOG_2009
```

**Edit 2:**

It's a SystemVerilog 2009 feature and Quartus Prime Standard and Quartus Prime Lite don't support VHDL 2008 or SystemVerilog 2009.

Quartus Prime Pro 19.4:

[image]

Quartus Prime Standard 19.1:

[image]

Comment: Yeah I tried excluding every file from project then changing their extension to .sv and reimporting them in the project (which had the same effect as your little trick but it required also changing the extension). Alas it is not working. I also told Quartus to compile my Verilog HDL as SystemVerilog but without success... At this point I don't even understand what is going wrong in this file...

Comment: Altough in my .qsf it mention this line : set_global_assignment -name VERILOG_INPUT_VERSION SYSTEMVERILOG_2005. Could the version be wrong? Haven't found a way to change it in Quartus itself.

Comment: If you can't find a place to change these values in the GUI itself, you can change the [settings](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/programmable/us/en/pdfs/literature/manual/mnl-pro-qsf-reference.pdf) in the `.qsf` directly. You can try changing the version to `SystemVerilog_2009` but I don't know if you'll see much difference. Is the error you see still the same as in the body?

Comment: Yes it's still the same error. I also recreated the project and imported my file which have .sv extensions now and I still get the same error. I'll go ahead and try 2009.

EDIT: Quartus simply deletes the change and retries compilation with the old 2005 parameter.

Comment: I see this warning `Warning(17326): Verilog HDL warning at multiplexer.sv(5): elaboration system task error violates IEEE 1800 (2005) syntax`, so perhaps the SystemVerilog 2009 *will* help.

Comment: Could you tell me what you did to get this warning? Because I don't have it and as I mentionned, modifying the .qsf file only makes Quartus reset the file.

Comment: I threw your code (with the fixes mentioned by Matthew Taylor) into a Quartus Prime Pro 19.4 project and ran "Analysis & Synthesis" with default settings. If I change to 2009 using the command above, I don't see the warning. What version of Quartus are you using? Also, you need to close Quartus before modifying the QSF, otherwise yes the active project will reset it.

Comment: I tried changing the 2005 to 2009 while Quartus was closed but now when I open my project I get this `125036 Assignment value SYSTEMVERILOG_2009 for assignment VERILOG_INPUT_VERSION is illegal`

Comment: I should also mention that I am using the lite version of Quartus Prime. When I look online I should be able to select SysteVerilog 2009 in the settings but I only have SystemVerilog as an option... PLease don't tell me you need to pay to get this feature...

Comment: I have Quartus Prime Lite 19.1 which i download a week ago... I'll go look into why I don't have the 19.4. EDIT: Yeah there is no version higher than 19.1 for the Lite version. You have the Pro version (I don't have the money for that because I'm a student)

Comment: I tested it in both standard and prime and yeah, that's the problem. Quartus Prime Standard and Quartus Prime Lite don't support VHDL 2008 or SystemVerilog 2009.

Comment: I'll accept you answer because it resolves the initial problem which was related to Quartus Prime in general and my problem now is more about the version I am using.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem...money...
If you look at the following image you'll notice that if you are poor you can't use
the latest version of SystemVerilog in the Lite and Standard version of Quartus Prime.
[image]

Well that explains it all.
If anyone as another solution to throw error at compile time that looks better than this please tell me:

```
generate
if (CONDITION > MAX_ALLOWED /* your condition check */ ) begin
    illegal_parameter_condition_triggered_will_instantiate_an non_existing_module();
end
endgenerate
```

Note: this was taken from https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/71226

Answer (score 0):

I see other errors:

- you are driving wire `out` from a procedural block (your `always`
  block). You cannot do that, you can only drive a variable. ie `out`
  must be a variable.
- your code inside the square brackets is illegal. You will need to use
  one of the `+:` or `-:` operators. See [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186389/for-loop-inside-an-always-block-with-conditional-statement-giving-unexpected-err/52186530#52186530).

Comment: Although the question seems to be about Verilog, note that $error etc are legal outside of procedural blocks, usually for the very purpose of generate block DRC, in SystemVerilog (elaboration system tasks.)

Comment: Thank you for the advice on this new operator. It is so much easier than having to think about it with those variables XD